# No option yo choose Download Updates while installing Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

While going through the installation setup i haven't given the choice to choose download updates while installing Ubuntu. Is that necessary? If yes then what can i do .

Comment: i prefer not to download updates during install; as I point to a local mirror (esp. when home as the mirror isn't quota-counted) when done & update post-install. No it's not necessary; you can do it post-reboot, or after install.  I do by choice.

Comment: And how i can update after install. Thanx in advance

Comment: i'm a terminal person (ie. prefer commands or 'codes') , so i'd login, press ctrl+alt+t to open a terminal, then enter command `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade`  which will update the repositories followed by (command after ;) install upgrades.   `sudo apt upgrade` would also update programs/apps, but would keep main version numbers the same; where as `dist-upgrade` gets all (allowing programs to jump to later versions too + allowing later kernels).  if you wait you should be prompted to install updates anyway.  (ctrl-d will exit terminal, or hit 'close' button)

Answer (score 0):

Installing updates during installation is not required. You can check for and install any available updates at any time after installation. Typically, Ubuntu checks for updates for you and displays an icon somewhere (depending on your desktop) to indicate that updates are available). Hover over icons to see if any involve updates. You can also check for updates by running any one of many apps that should be available in your start menu. Such apps are "Ubuntu Software", "Software Updater", "Software", "Synaptic Package Manager", and "Update Manager" just to name a few. Try any of the above.